# Difference between switch cases "@unknown default" and "default" in Swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

From Swift 5, new case attribute `@unknown` is introduced.

What is the exact difference when `@unknown` is being used and not being used? In which case we have to use `@unknown` keyword?

Comment: Please read [SE-0192](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md) and watch [this video](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/126/whats-new-in-swift-5-0) about the most important news in Swift 5

Answer (score 23):

From [SE-0192: Handling Future Enum Cases](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md) (emphasis mine):

> When switching over a non-frozen `enum`, the `switch` statement that
>   matches against it must include a catch-all case (usually `default` or
>   an "ignore" `_` pattern).
>
> ```
> switch excuse {
> case .eatenByPet:
>   // …
> case .thoughtItWasDueNextWeek:
>   // …
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to do so will produce a warning in Swift 5. A program will
>   trap at run time if an unknown enum case is actually encountered.
>
> All other uses of enums (`if case`, creation, accessing members, etc)
>   do not change. Only the exhaustiveness checking of switches is
>   affected by the frozen/non-frozen distinction. Non-exhaustive switches
>   over frozen enums (and boolean values) will continue to be invalid in
>   all language modes.
>
> Here's a more complicated example:
>
> ```
> switch (excuse, notifiedTeacherBeforeDeadline) {
> case (.eatenByPet, true):
>   // …
> case (.thoughtItWasDueNextWeek, true):
>   // …
> case (_, false):
>   // …
> }
> ```
>
> This switch handles all known patterns, but still doesn't account for
>   the possibility of a new enum case when the second tuple element is
>   `true`. This should result in a warning in Swift 5, like the first
>   example.
>
> #### `@unknown`
>
> The downside of using a default case is that the compiler can no
>   longer alert a developer that a particular enum has elements that
>   aren't explicitly handled in the switch. To remedy this, `switch`
>   cases will gain a new attribute, `@unknown`.
>
> ```
> switch excuse {
> case .eatenByPet:
>   // …
> case .thoughtItWasDueNextWeek:
>   // …
> @unknown default:
>   // …
> }
> ```
>
> Like the regular default, `@unknown` default matches any value; it is
>   a "catch-all" case. However, the compiler will produce a warning if
>   all known elements of the enum have not already been matched. This is
>   a warning rather than an error so that adding new elements to the enum
>   remains a source-compatible change. (This is also why @unknown default
>   matches any value rather than just those not seen at compile-time.)
>
> `@unknown` may only be applied to default or a case consisting of the
>   single pattern _. Even in the latter case, `@unknown` must be used
>   with the last case in a switch. This restriction is discussed further
>   in the "unknown patterns" section under "Future directions".
>
> The compiler will warn if all enums in the pattern being matched by
>   @unknown are explicitly annotated as frozen, or if there are no enums
>   in the pattern at all. This is a warning rather than an error so that
>   annotating an enum as frozen remains a source-compatible change. If
>   the pattern contains any enums that are implicitly frozen (i.e.
>   because it is a user-defined Swift enum), @unknown is permitted, in
>   order to make it easier to adapt to newly-added cases.
>
> `@unknown` has a downside that it is not **testable**, since there is
>   no way to create an `enum` value that does not match any known cases,
>   and there wouldn't be a safe way to use it if there was one. However,
>   combining `@unknown` with other cases using fallthrough can get the
>   effect of following another case's behavior while still getting
>   compiler warnings for new cases.
>
> ```
> switch excuse {
> case .eatenByPet:
>   showCutePicturesOfPet()
>
> case .thoughtItWasDueNextWeek:
>   fallthrough
> @unknown default:
>   askForDueDateExtension()
> }
> ```

Comment: As a developer, I would prefer the compilation to fail in case a new value is added to an Enum, rather than see a warning. I really don't understand how's the "@unknown" is useful

Comment: @dor506, I think the idea is to allow Apple to update the Swift Standard Library as part of future iOS updates without breaking apps that were compiled against earlier versions. I think previously, the standard library is included in every app's binary. Check out [SE-0192](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md) for more information.

Comment: @dor506, I prefer the same!

Answer (score 19):

In the case of only using `default`, it's used as when our `switch` doesn't match any of the options. Let's see a first exhaustive case:

```
enum Option {
  case A
  case B
}

func optionSelected(option: Option) {
  switch(option) {
    case .A:
      print("You chose A!")
    case .B:
      print("You chose B!")
  }
}
```

This example is exhaustive and we won't get any error. But what if we need to add options in our `enum`?

```
enum Option {
  case A
  case B
  case C
}

func optionSelected(option: Option) {
  switch(option) {
    case .A:
      print("You chose A!")
    case .B:
      print("You chose B!")
  }
}
```

In this second example, we will get an error `Switch must be exhaustive`. To avoid this error, we might implement a default case:

```
enum Option {
  case A
  case B
  case C
}

func optionSelected(option: Option) {
  switch(option) {
    case .A:
      print("You chose A!")
    case .B:
      print("You chose B!")
    default:
      print("You chose other option!")
  }
}
```

If the user chose, Option C, he will fall into the default case. But what happens when we add an Option D, E, etc. into the Enum? If we don't change the `switch` they will all fall into `default`. This might not be a problem, depending on what you want to implement.

Now, with the `@unknown`, we continue catching all the other options, but the difference here is that the compiler we issue a warning `Switch must be exhaustive` (not an error!) if all known elements of the enum haven't been matched (i.e. the switch wasn't exhaustive).

```
enum Option2 {
  case A
  case B
  case C
}

func optionSelected2(option: Option2) {
  switch(option) {
    case .A:
      print("You chose A!")
    case .B:
      print("You chose B!")
    case .C:
      print("You chose C!")
    @unknown default:
      print("You chose other option!")
  }
}
```

If we add an option D, E, etc, we will just see a warning and then decide if we want to implement the other cases (for example, we want a custom message for option D and E) or if we will just leave the default message "you chose another option". Think of it as a friendly remainder instead of a big red error :)

Other examples: https://www.raywenderlich.com/55728-what-s-new-in-swift-5

Comment: In theory this new case sounds useful, but the problem is, you will now have a permanent warning saying default will never be used and would prefer to have no warnings in my project

Comment: @AdamM Yes but then you just fix the warning by adding another case to your switch.

Answer (score 14):

The answers that imply that you will ever get a warning for *your* enums are wrong. This is about how Swift treats C (and Objective-C) enums in an external library/framework. A *few* Swift standard library enums are affected.

Okay, so let's consider an actual example. We write an exhaustive switch against a Cocoa enum:

```
    var err : [URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason] = ...
    switch err {
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.cellular: break
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.expensive: break
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.constrained: break
    }
```

At this point we get a warning. Why?

Well, our switch is exhaustive *now*, but it might not *always* be exhaustive. What if the framework adds cases later? Our compiled code won't change, and so it will crash (trap) when the new case arrives into the switch.

So we need a way to allow our code to keep working even if the framework changes. The compiler therefore is telling us: "Add a default case, even though the switch is exhaustive."

Now, of course it would be possible to add an *ordinary* default case:

```
    switch err {
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.cellular: break
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.expensive: break
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.constrained: break
    default: break
    }
```

The problem with that is if the framework *does* change, we'll never hear about it. So there's a better way, `@unknown default`:

```
    switch err {
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.cellular: break
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.expensive: break
    case URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.constrained: break
    @unknown default: break
    }
```

This means: "Hey, compiler, I don't expect there to be any more cases, but if I ever try to compile this project against the framework and you discover that there is another case, *warn me* so that I can add it explicitly to my switch."

So that's what's special about `@unknown`. If another case is added behind our backs, the compiler will give us *another warning* telling us about it, and we can fix our code to include it. In other words, you obey the warning *now* to get rid of the warning *now* in exchange for a possible useful warning *in the future*.

Another nice thing about this syntax is that if we add an `@unknown default` to a switch that is *not* exhaustive *now*, the compiler will warn us about *that*.

Answer (score 10):

[**default case**](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html)

> Every switch statement must be exhaustive. That is, every possible value of the type being considered must be matched by one of the switch cases. If it’s not appropriate to provide a case for every possible value, you can define a default case to cover any values that are not addressed explicitly. This default case is indicated by the default keyword, and must always appear last.

For example:

```
let someCharacter: Character = "z"
switch someCharacter {
case "a":
    print("The first letter of the alphabet")
case "z":
    print("The last letter of the alphabet")
default:
    print("Some other character")
}
```

> The switch statement’s first case matches the first letter of the English alphabet, a, and its second case matches the last letter, z. Because the switch must have a case for every possible character, not just every alphabetic character, this switch statement uses a **default case** to match all characters other than a and z. This provision ensures that the switch statement is exhaustive

[**@unknown default case**](https://forums.swift.org/t/handling-unknown-cases-in-enums-re-se-0192/7388)

From [Reinder's blog post on "What's New In Swift 5.0"](https://learnappmaking.com/swift-5-whats-new/):

> In Swift 5.0, a new `@unknown` keyword can be added to the `default`
>   switch case. This doesn’t change the behavior of `default`, so this
>   case will still match any cases that aren’t handled in the rest of the
>   `switch` block.
>
> ```
> switch fruit {
> case .apple:
>     ... 
> @unknown default:
>     print("We don't sell that kind of fruit here.")
> }
> ```
>
> The `@unknown` keyword will trigger a warning in Xcode if you’re
>   dealing with a potentially non-exhaustive `switch` statement, because
>   of a changed enumeration. You can deliberately consider this new case,
>   thanks to the warning, which wasn’t possible with just `default`.
>
> And the good thing is that due to how `default` works, your code won’t
>   break if new cases are added to the enum – but you do get warned.
>   Neat!

more Ref: [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/126/whats-new-in-swift-5-0)

Comment: "case" before @unknown default is giving error.. no need to include it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will warn you if the cases are extended in the meantime. If you don't use this keyword, and extend the cases later, you may forget to update the code everywhere. This keyword helps you for later use.